# Elmah - inspect server variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

When debugging with [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), is there any way to inspect the actual variables in an exception?

I know that I can find the http-get/post variables in the querystring/form section, but is there any way to see the current values of variables in the method where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elamh does not have direct support for that, in fact even .NET does not provide this type of support natively. You can see this previous question [Values of local variables in C# after exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087595/values-of-local-variables-in-c-sharp-after-exception) where the way that a third-party tool handles the capturing of local variables during an exception.

You can use this an example and build your own exception handling and throw a custom error type to Elmah via something similar to the following:

```
 try
 {

   ...
 } 
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext()
       .Raise(new CustomException(ex,<insert method variables here>));
 }
```